# photo gallery in php/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, photo-gallery

I'm looking for a plugin for photo gallery in php/ jquery/ mysql to get the photos from the database that would look like this:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/organizer/organizer.html

Organizing Images into Albums using php/jquery

Anyone?

Comment: look like that in what sense? "administrable" files?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are looking more at organazing/managing photos than files in general and Coppermine is pretty much just does that.
[Coppermine gallery functionality.](http://documentation.coppermine-gallery.net/en/albums.htm#albmgr)

> "Coppermine stores files inside of
>   albums, so you'll need at least one
>   album for your pictures/files to be
>   placed in. Albums can be stored in
>   categories (but they don't HAVE to be
>   in a category, they can just as well
>   go into the coppermine "root"). When
>   you click on "albums" in the admin
>   menu, you will see the Album Manager."

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job I guess:

[6 New File Managers Based on jQuery, Ajax, php](http://www.dreamcss.com/2009/07/file-managers-based-on-jquery-ajax-php.html)

Good luck, hope this was what you were looking for!